# Derivative of Lagrangian with respect to a vector

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation

Sometimes to find an equation of motion, the Lagrangian is derivated with respect to the (position) vector. How can this be possible?

Comment: $\partial L/\partial\vec{x}\triangleq\sum\partial L/\partial x_i$.

Comment: And @Kyle Kanos, why is it the sum? Sometimes its written as a gradient which is just another vector...

Comment: @KyleKanos Please don't use comments to answer questions --- especially not cryptic answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can take the derivative with respect to each *component* of the vector and then assemble that list of results into another vector (the gradient). In other words, $\partial L/\partial \vec x$ is sometimes used as an abbreviation for the quantity $\vec\nabla L$ with components $\partial L/\partial x_i$.

To be more careful, we should distinguish between covariant and contravariant vectors (or between vectors and one-forms), but those distinctions are probably beside the point of the question.